# How to rename multiple csv files in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I have large number of csv files like the format below

t_s295447.csv
t_s295453.csv
t_s295459.csv

I want to rename them to this format below

A01_t_s295447.csv
A01_t_s295453.csv
A01_t_s295459.csv

Comment: You did not say which shell you are using. You could use the `rename` command (which is an external command), or you can use zsh and there use the `zmv` function. I suggest you have a look at both to see which one you find more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

I often use this pattern

`for f in t_*.csv ; do mv $f A01_$f ; done`

Or in a script

```
for f in t_*.csv 
do
  echo $f A01_$f
  mv $f A01_$f
done
```

for bulk renames. For more complex problems, I use `sed` to create the new name. I comment out the mv until the echo shows me that the renames will be right.